# Xcode Playground Stuck at Running State

Tags: xcode, macos

I have this code in my Xcode Playground.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

func calcBMI(weight : Double, height : Double) -> String {

    let bmi = weight / pow(height, 2)

    let ShortenBMI = String(format: "%.2f", bmi)


    var result = ""

    if bmi > 25 {
        result = "You're overweight."
    }else if  bmi > 18.5 {
        result = "You're normal weight."
    } else {
        result = "You're underweight."
    }

    return "Your BMI is" + String(ShortenBMI) + " and " +  result
}

var bmiResult = calcBMI(weight : 85, height : 1.8 )

print (bmiResult)
```

I am not sure why my Xcode seems to stuck on running.

[image]

Is there a way to check to see what went wrong?

I tried restart my Xcode and see the same result.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to happen from time to time, I prefer to set my playgrounds to run manually (you can do that by clicking on the little square button below your code until a contextual menu is shown).

Answer (score 0):

It's all because of iCloud. If you check iCloud drive options in the Settings you will find that Playground is constantly syncing by default.

Just go to:

System Preferences - Apple ID - Apps on this Mac using iCloud- iCloud Drive - Options- And then uncheck "Playground"

That little trick prevents syncing and resolves the frozen "Running".

[image: Prevent Playground from sync]